How to get mouseover to fire when interactive container moves behind the pointer in pixi js?
I have a situation in a pixi js game where a mouse click picks a location for a sprite to move on a tiled platform and then the platform moves behind the sprite until it's on the selected tile.
The current logic is on mouseover, I save which tile is selected and on click, I move the platform to the selected tile. This works when you're moving the pointer over a tile, but when the platform moves a new clickable tile behind the pointer a mouseover is not fired. Is there a way I can get mouseover to fire when an interactive element moves behind the pointer instead of just when the pointer moves over an interactive element?
An alternative might be to check the coordinates of the pointer after the platform moves and then set the clickable tile, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way to do it as I don't have an easy way at this point to make a point on the screen to a tile.
I'm using pixi js 8.1.1.
EDIT: Adding example. If you mouse over the rectangle it turns black, but if you click it and the rectangle slides under your pointer while it's not moving, it does not.


const { Application, Container, Assets, Sprite, Graphics, RenderTexture, GraphicsContext } = PIXI;

const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
let app, renderer, platform;

const trailGraphics = new Graphics();

window.onload = async () => {
  renderer = await PIXI.autoDetectRenderer({});
  const app = new Application();
  await app.init({ background: '#9cc3ff', width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight, antialias: true, autoDensity: true, resolution: window.devicePixelRatio });
  document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);

  const g = new Graphics()
    .beginFill(`#ff0000`)
    .drawRect(0, 0, 300, 200)
    .endFill();
  const container = new Container();
  container.interactive = true;
  container.buttonMode = true;
  container.x = 0;
  container.y = 0;
  container.addChild(g);
  app.stage.addChild(container);

  container.addListener(`mouseover`, function () {
    this.tint = `#00ff00`;
  });
  container.addListener(`mouseout`, function () {
    this.tint = `#ff0000`;
  });
  container.addListener(`click`, function () {
    container.x = 500;
    this.tint = `#ff0000`;
  });

  app.ticker.add(time => {
    if (container.x > 0) {
      container.x -= 5;
    }
  });
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/8.1.1/pixi.min.js"></script>




Please include a [mre].

container.on('pointerenter', () => {/*your code here*/});

